# Typescript: Map.has doesn't return correct value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm iterating through a typescript array and adding objects to a map. The keys should be unique, so I check if they already exist with Map.has

However, for some reason it does not return the correct value and adds duplicate keys. Please check my code:

```
    for (const userAccount of res) {

        // create key if doesn't exist
        if (!this.sourceSystemsUserAccounts.has(userAccount.sourceSystem)) {
            this.sourceSystemsUserAccounts.set(userAccount.sourceSystem, new Array<UserAccount>());
        }

        // add user account to map and set new array
        const value: Array<UserAccount> = this.sourceSystemsUserAccounts.get(userAccount.sourceSystem);
        value.push(userAccount);
        this.sourceSystemsUserAccounts.set(userAccount.sourceSystem, value);
    }
```

They key (source system object) looks like this:

```
export class SourceSystems implements BaseEntity {
    constructor(
        public id?: number,
        public name?: string,
        public identifier?: string,
        public currencies?: Array<Currency>,
        public lendingActivated?: boolean,
        public walletApiActivated?: boolean,
    ) {
        this.lendingActivated = false;
    }
}
```

After the third iteration my map looks like this:
[image: Map in Chrome debugger]

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE: Here you can see a preview of the full response object:
[image: response object]

Comment: Can you post your full response object which has `userAccount`

Comment: You're using object as a key and I believe they (objects) are not equal by reference (deserialized from JSON or something like this)

Comment: is `userAccount.sourceSystem` is an object or a string value?

Comment: userAccount.sourceSystem is an object. But it should be exactly the same object in several iterations. You can also see this by the ID. Nothing has been manipulated since fetching it.

Comment: @Niladri I added (one object) of the response object. Please see the original thread, I updated it.

Comment: Even if objects have same properties they not equal by reference `{ foo: 1} != { foo: 1}`

Comment: it's better to add them in map by using a single property of the `userAccount.sourceSystem` object rather the full object because they will always be different even if the property values are equal

Comment: @dave0688 try to use `userAccount.sourceSystem.name` as the key to the `map` it will not allow duplicate names as key according to your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. You're right, two objects are not the same by reference. I wanted to have an object as key because I need more values out of the key. But I gotta think of another solution then. Thanks all for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a class as a key aka. `class SourceSystems`. Two instances of the class are not *equal*. Hence the duplicate.

## One Solution

Use string keys for the map.